# Highcharts - inject data with variables

Tags: json, highcharts, papaparse

I would like to use dynamic data to inject into the pie. I have been doing this so far : https://codepen.io/Surunairdopera/pen/gOPgKrv
I have before this code a CSV file which I transform into a JSON file by using Papa parse. I create a json object composed of the 5 data I want to use in my pie. But highcharts doesn't accept this data.

```
  $(document).ready(function() {

   let file = "X.csv";
 Papa.parse(file, {
        download: true,
        header: true,
        delimiter:";",
        complete: function(results) {
            let dataDetail = results.data;
            objJSONDetail = dataDetail.find(element => element.ticket == ticket);
            let objJSONX = {
                                Donnee1: objJSONDetail.donnee1,
                                Donne2: objJSONDetail.donnee2,
                                Donnee3: objJSONDetail.donnee3,
                                Donnee4: objJSONDetail.donnee4,
                                Donnee5: objJSONDetail.donne5                                
                                }   
         console.log(objJSONX['Donnee1']);//return the data, i would like to use for the pie

}
```

I'm new at using Highcharts so, be nice ;)

***UPDATE***
I found the reason why :
I wrote variable as STRING. Highcharts expects numerical values. So it works with a parseFloat :
parseFloat(objJSONDetail.donnee1);

Comment: Hi @Claire, Please provide me with the value of `objJSONX` variable.

Comment: thanks @ppotaczek for your response, I fixed the issue meanwhile and update the post : )